# How to upgrade Windows PowerShell to v7.2.6

Tags: windows, powershell, upgrade

I am using Microsoft Window1 Home on a 64 bit computer, and am using Windows PowerShell 7.2.5

I just opened my PowerShell today and it told me "A new PowerShell stable release is available: v7.2.6
Upgrade now, or check out the release page at: [https://aka.ms/PowerShell-Release?tag=v7.2.6"](https://aka.ms/PowerShell-Release?tag=v7.2.6%22)

I looked at the release page but could not figure out from how to update it from the webpage.

I then tried the command `winget upgrade Microsoft PowersShell` but got the error message `` Found a positional argument where none was expected: `PowerShell` ``

Any help in figuring out how to update this PowerShell would be greatly appreciated!

Other info about my computer:
Version: 10.0.22000 Build 22000
System Model: Inspiron 7570
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why use wget?

Just directly download the MSI (installer) locally and install it.

If you want to do this via code directly in PS, then do this:

```
Invoke-Expression "& { $(Invoke-RestMethod https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) } -UseMSI"
```

When you install the latest version, it will ask you to allow for automatic updates via Windows Update for all future updates.

Comment: This was really helpful and worked perfectly! Thank you! How did you find this out however? I was trying to google an answer and did not come across anything like this.

Comment: No worries, glad it was a resolution for you. As for the posted solution. This approach has been on the web for a few years now. Since PSv6. I've had this in my launch profile for a very long time as a check for the new version and it will launch if there is one. Yet, with the latest release, and the WU integration, I've commented it out. I keep it around as this question does come up from time to time. BTW, no need for 'Wget', as PowerShell has had a package manager for a while now. PowerShellGet, and well, it uses 'Wget' under the covers anyway. There are other reasons to use 'Wget though.

Comment: There have been/are other approaches as well. For Example: 
[How to Install and Update PowerShell 7](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/07/how-to-install-and-update-powershell-7), and this,[How to keep PowerShell Core up to date using Windows Terminal](https://tomssl.com/how-to-keep-powershell-core-up-to-date-using-windows-terminal), but again, after the Microsft changes for updates, it mostly moot. As for  WGet thing, read up on [PowerShellGet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershellget-3-0-preview-12-release/).